# Reading Huge Data With Java

Tags: java, regex, logging, bigdata, filechannel

Firstly, I'm sorry about my English.

I looking for an effective a way to read a Big file in java. I make a log analysis program and I have log files at least from 500 MB to 4 GB. I have tried the Filechannel class (Memory Mapped files), but I could not get effective result. Take a look here: http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/thinking_in_java/TIJ314_029.htm

My purpose is read the data in the buffer, and then using regular expression.

DumpFilePath file size is about 4 GB.

```
public static List<String> anaysis_main(String pattern_string) throws IOException {

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern_string, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);


    File file = new File(DumpFilePath);

    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
    String line = null;
    raf.seek(0);


    int i = 0;

    while((line=raf.readLine())!=null)
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        while (matcher.find())
        {               
            result.add(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
    raf.close();

    return result;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `FileChannel` _is_ the way to go; however, mapping is limited in size to something like 2 GB, so you'll have to do "sliding windows" for reading.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted...  Are people sneering because "4Gb is tiny compared to what *I* work on!"? Or because the English is a bit creaky (which s/he apologises for)?  Grow up.  The question is perfectly clear: "How can I apply a regex to a 4Gb file?"

Comment: Here is one suggestion: is the file divided into smaller units (e.g. lines) in such a way that the regexes you want to apply never span multiple units?  If so then just read a unit at a time into memory, and apply your regexes to each.

Comment: Since you say your data is line oriented, why don't you use a plain `BufferedReader`?

Comment: @j_random_hacker 
  RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file,"rw");
  String line = null;
  raf.seek(0);
  String data = "";
  

  int i = 0;
  
  while((line=raf.readLine())!=null)
  {
   i++;
   System.out.println(i);
   //Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
   //while (matcher.find())
      //{       
      // result.add(matcher.group(1));
      //}
  }
  bar_load.setValue(100);
  raf.close();
  
     frame_load.setVisible(false);
     return result;
this is my source code
but Still takes a long time....
Is this you say to me right?

Comment: Paste your code in your question, please

Comment: @fge sorry!! i have uploaded source code

Comment: result is where to store the result of regular experssion .

Comment: Why is it not effective (in terms of memory usage of CPU usage for instance)? What problems are you having?

Comment: @HyunwooKim: Yes, the code you included in your question is more or less what I intended.  What is "a long time"?  Bear in mind it takes a while to do anything with a 4Gb file!  If it takes less than twice the time needed to copy the file, then I think it's doing pretty well.  Otherwise, it might be that `result` is getting very big, meaning that a lot of time will be spent allocating memory.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a Buffered reader?  More can be read on the [buffered reader here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html).

The code would look something like this:

```
File file = new File(DumpFilePath);

//Open the file for reading
try {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 

    // Your line by line parsing payload here

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(thisLine);
    while (matcher.find())
    {               
        result.add(matcher.group(1));
        }

} // end while 
} // end try
catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println("Error: " + e);
}
```